# SQLite: How does order of execution work given a CASE WHEN subquery?

Tags: sql, sqlite

The below code is part of a working SQLite pull. Can someone explain how the WHEN section works? It leverages a subquery in the parenthesis. I thought that a subquery would execute prior to the outer query. In that case how can `country = c.country` work? Doesn't c.country only exist once the outer query executes?

```
WITH country_or_other AS
    (
     SELECT
       CASE
           WHEN (
                 SELECT count(*)
                 FROM customer
                 where country = c.country
                ) = 1 THEN "Other"
           ELSE c.country
       END AS country,
       c.customer_id,
       il.*
     FROM invoice_line il
     INNER JOIN invoice i ON i.invoice_id = il.invoice_id
     INNER JOIN customer c ON c.customer_id = i.customer_id
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In every row of your query there is the column `c.country` from the joined table `customer`.
So for every row of your query, this query:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM customer
where country = c.country
```

is executed and returns the number of rows in the table `customer` where the column `country` is equal to the value of `c.country`.
This number is compared to `1` and the `CASE` expression returns either `'Other'` or the value of `c.country`.
This is how I would write this code:

```
WITH country_or_other AS
    (
     SELECT
       CASE
           WHEN t.counter = 1 THEN "Other"
           ELSE c.country
       END AS country,
       c.customer_id,
       il.*
     FROM invoice_line il
     INNER JOIN invoice i ON i.invoice_id = il.invoice_id
     INNER JOIN customer c ON c.customer_id = i.customer_id
     INNER JOIN (SELECT country, count(*) counter FROM customer GROUP BY country) t ON t.country = c.country 
    )
```

I assume the column `country` in the table `customer` is not `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks, makes complete sense.  That is quite helpful for me to re-frame the code in my mind.

Comment: Hi @forpas from where you got data of customer and country.?

Answer (score 0):

You have a correlated subquery.  Conceptually, the subquery is run for every row generated by the outer query.  Each run has a different value for the external reference.

However, a correlated subquery is not needed:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.country) = 1
             THEN 'Other'
             ELSE c.country
        END) AS country,
        c.customer_id,
        il.*
 FROM invoice_line il JOIN
      invoice i 
      ON i.invoice_id = il.invoice_id JOIN
      customer c
      ON c.customer_id = i.customer_id
```

Comment: Great, thank you.  Your answer very much helps on what was a mental sticking point for me.

Comment: HI @gordon From where i can create above tables to practice your query. ?

Comment: @PIG . . . You can use online database interfaces such as db<>fiddle.

Comment: I meant from where i can get data to practice ?